# docker-compose port expose not working on mac 10.13.6 (High Sierra)

Tags: docker, docker-compose, containers, dockerfile

I have a docker container that hosts a Node application. I am trying to connect the application using following URL https://localhost:8000, but the connection is refused. I used `docker-compose up -d` command to run it.

This is the response I get when I run `docker-compose ps`

```
           Name                  Command      State           Ports         
-----------------------------------------------------------------------------
freeswitch-console_console_1   nodemon start   Up      0.0.0.0:8000->8000/tcp
```

My docker-compose file is

```
version: '3'
services:
  console:
    build: .
    ports:
    - "8000:8000"
    image: console:cp
    volumes:
    - .:/usr/src/app
    - /usr/src/app/node_modules
```

And my Dockerfile is

```
FROM node:10

# Create app directory
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
# A wildcard is used to ensure both package.json AND package-lock.json are copied
# where available (npm@5+)

RUN npm install -g nodemon

COPY package*.json ./


RUN npm install
# If you are building your code for production
# RUN npm install --only=production

# Bundle app source
COPY . .

EXPOSE 8000
CMD [ "nodemon", "start" ]
```

I tried following command and it didn't work either:

```
docker run -p 8000:8000 console:cp nodemon index.js
```

Some more details

```
docker-compose version 1.22.0, build f46880f
Docker version 18.06.0-ce, build 0ffa825
MacOSX 10.13.6 (High Sierra)
```

Any ideas? Thanks in advance.

Comment: What's the output of the server when you run it?

Comment: Sorry I updated the original question.

Comment: Can you verify that the node app actually runs and is bound to port 8000?

Comment: I would run this command `docker run -p 8000:80 nginx` just to make sure if its a problem with the OS that don't allow expose of if its a problem with your app.

Comment: @gesellix yes it is: server.listen(8000, '0.0.0.0', function(){
    console.log("server running at https://localhost:8000/")
  });

Comment: Did you expect the app to be available via `https` or via `http` protocol? In your question you mentioned `https`.

Comment: Also: you're using a volume mount to map your local directory into the container. Please beware that native node modules might not work inside the container, because macOS binaries aren't necessarily compatible with the Debian based node.js image.

Comment: @Noa it didn't work either. It says localhost refused to connect.

Comment: @gesellix Its using https.

Comment: @gesellix yes I understand that native node modules won't work. But I am not using any native node module.

Comment: @TezroSolutions But the image started?
If so, I recommend you to perform below steps:
Run again NGINX
`docker run -p 8000:80 nginx`
When the container is up and running, check if the ports are open
`lsof -i -n -P | grep docker`
If they are open use CURL to test
`curl 127.0.0.1:8000`
If you don't get result form curl and the port is open I would check for firewall settings

Comment: @Noa `lsof -i -n -P | grep docker` prints nothing. curl command prints this: `curl: (7) Failed to connect to 127.0.0.1 port 8000: Connection refused
`

Comment: @Noa the docker run command just kept the terminal busy, how can I tell if it is running?

Comment: @Noa never mind this is what docker ps renders `CONTAINER ID        IMAGE               COMMAND                  CREATED             STATUS              PORTS                  NAMES
7a985f949c30        nginx               "nginx -g 'daemon of…"   27 minutes ago      Up 27 minutes       0.0.0.0:8000->80/tcp   gracious_poincare`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In the end I removed the Docker daemon configuration which were set to following

```
{
 "debug" : true,
 "userland-proxy" : false,
 "experimental" : true
}
```

It started working. I think it has to do with userland-proxy.

Thanks everybody for help.